# RecyclerView does not display data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display data from an API.
Because of a HttpLoggingInterceptor, I am sure that I receive the data, but it doesn't get displayed in my recyclerview. Is there anyone that knows what I might be doing wrong?

I have also tried just putting a textview in the recyclerview, but even that doesn't show.

After some more debugging, I found out that "adapter.submitlist(it!!.docs)" in BookListFragment.kt never happens. Why would that be?

I would greatly appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

**fragment_book_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="booklist.BookListFragment">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvBooks"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notfounderror"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="185dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**book_in_list.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="book"
            type="be.nienke.eindopdracht.api.Q" />
        <variable
            name="clicklistener"
            type="be.nienke.eindopdracht.book.BookClickListener" />
    </data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{() -> clicklistener.onClick(book)}">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookTitleTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@{book.title}"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/authorTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/auteur"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bookTitleTv" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookAuthorTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@{book.author_name[0]}"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/authorTv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bookTitleTv" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberOfPagesTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/aantal_pagina_s"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bookAuthorTv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bookTitleTv" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookNumberOfPagesTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@{book.number_of_pages_median.toString()}"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/numberOfPagesTv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bookTitleTv" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/languageTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/taal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bookNumberOfPagesTv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bookTitleTv"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookLanguageTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@{book.language[0].toString()}"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/languageTv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bookTitleTv" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

**BookListFragment.kt**

```
package be.nienke.eindopdracht.booklist

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import be.nienke.eindopdracht.R
import be.nienke.eindopdracht.book.BookAdapter
import be.nienke.eindopdracht.book.BookClickListener
import be.nienke.eindopdracht.databinding.FragmentBookListBinding
import be.nienke.eindopdracht.user.UserSingelton


class BookListFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentBookListBinding
    private lateinit var viewmodel: BookListViewModel
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_book_list, container, false)
        val user = UserSingelton.instance().user
        val search = BookListFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments()).search
        val viewModelFactory = BookListViewModelFactory(user!!, search)
        viewmodel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(BookListViewModel::class.java)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        val adapter = BookAdapter(BookClickListener {
            viewmodel.onBookClicked(it)
        })
        binding.rvBooks.adapter = adapter
        val manager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        binding.rvBooks.layoutManager = manager
        viewmodel._nonFoundError.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                binding.notfounderror.setError(it)
            }
        })
        viewmodel._baseBookTitle.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                adapter.submitList(it!!.docs)
            }
        })
        viewmodel._book.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                requireView().findNavController().navigate(BookListFragmentDirections.actionBookListFragmentToBookFragment(it))
                viewmodel.navigateToBookFinished()
            }
        })
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
    return binding.root
    }

}
```

**BookListViewModel.kt**

```
import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import be.nienke.eindopdracht.BookAPI
import be.nienke.eindopdracht.Database.User
import be.nienke.eindopdracht.api.Base_BookTitle
import be.nienke.eindopdracht.api.Q
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.lang.Exception

class BookListViewModel(__user: User, __search : String): ViewModel() {
   var _user = MutableLiveData<User>()
    val user : LiveData<User>
    get() {
        return _user
    }
    var _search = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val search : LiveData<String>
    get(){
        return _search
    }
    var _baseBookTitle = MutableLiveData<Base_BookTitle?>()
    val baseBooktitle : LiveData<Base_BookTitle?>
    get(){
        return _baseBookTitle
    }
    var _nonFoundError = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    val nonFoundError : LiveData<String?>
    get() {
        return _nonFoundError
    }
    var _book = MutableLiveData<Q?>()
    val book : LiveData<Q?>
    get() {
        return _book
    }
    init {
        _user.value = __user
        _search.value = __search
        _nonFoundError.value = null
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                _baseBookTitle.value = BookAPI.retrofitService.getBooksByTitle(_search.value!!)
                if(_baseBookTitle.value!!.numFound == 0){
                    _nonFoundError.value == "Er zijn geen boeken gevonden voor deze zoekopdracht."
                }
            }
            catch (e: Exception){
                print(e.localizedMessage)
            }

        }
    }
    fun onBookClicked(book: Q){
        _book.value = book
    }
    fun navigateToBookFinished(){
        _book.value = null
    }
}
```

**BookAdapter.kt**

```
package be.nienke.eindopdracht.book

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import be.nienke.eindopdracht.api.Q
import be.nienke.eindopdracht.databinding.BookInListBinding
import be.nienke.eindopdracht.databinding.FragmentBookBinding

class BookAdapter(val clickListener: BookClickListener ): androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter<Q, BookAdapter.ViewHolder>(BookDiffCallBack()) {
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position)!!, clickListener)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder.from(parent)
    }
    class ViewHolder private constructor( val binding: BookInListBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        fun bind(item: Q, clickListener: BookClickListener){
            binding.book = item
            binding.clicklistener = clickListener
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
        companion object{
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder{
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = BookInListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return ViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }
}
class BookDiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Q>(){
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Q, newItem: Q): Boolean {
        return oldItem.key== newItem.key
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Q, newItem: Q): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
class BookClickListener(val clicklistener: (q: Q)-> Unit){
    fun onClick(q: Q)= clicklistener(q)
}
```

**Logcat when I test the API**

```
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=Is%20er%20iets (738ms)
D/OkHttp: Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
    Date: Sun, 09 Jan 2022 18:11:27 GMT
    Content-Type: application/json
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Access-Control-Allow-Method: GET, OPTIONS
    Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
D/OkHttp: X-OL-Stats: "SR 1 0.117 TT 0 0.118"
    Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
D/OkHttp: {
D/OkHttp:     "numFound": 1,
        "start": 0,
        "numFoundExact": true,
        "docs": [
            {
                "key": "/works/OL3764515W",
D/OkHttp:             "type": "work",
                "seed": [
                    "/books/OL1286559M",
                    "/works/OL3764515W",
D/OkHttp:                 "/subjects/history",
D/OkHttp:                 "/subjects/television_broadcasting",
                    "/subjects/television_programs",
                    "/subjects/place:netherlands",
                    "/authors/OL662730A"
D/OkHttp:             ],
                "title": "Is er nog iets leuks vanavond?",
                "title_suggest": "Is er nog iets leuks vanavond?",
                "has_fulltext": false,
                "edition_count": 1,
                "edition_key": [
                    "OL1286559M"
                ],
                "publish_date": [
                    "1991"
D/OkHttp:             ],
D/OkHttp:             "publish_year": [
                    1991
                ],
D/OkHttp:             "first_publish_year": 1991,
                "number_of_pages_median": 216,
D/OkHttp:             "lccn": [
                    "92145492"
                ],
                "publish_place": [
D/OkHttp:                 "Utrecht"
D/OkHttp:             ],
                "oclc": [
D/OkHttp:                 "27188277"
                ],
                "lcc": [
                    "PN-1992.30000000.N4 V43 1991"
                ],
                "isbn": [
                    "9027428840",
                    "9789027428844"
D/OkHttp:             ],
                "last_modified_i": 1605489709,
                "ebook_count_i": 0,
                "publisher": [
                    "Spectrum"
                ],
                "language": [
                    "dut"
                ],
D/OkHttp:             "author_key": [
                    "OL662730A"
                ],
D/OkHttp:             "author_name": [
                    "Bert van der Veer"
                ],
                "place": [
                    "Netherlands"
                ],
D/OkHttp:             "subject": [
                    "History",
D/OkHttp:                 "Television broadcasting",
                    "Television programs"
                ],
                "id_goodreads": [
                    "6427531"
                ],
                "id_librarything": [
                    "5541711"
                ],
                "publisher_facet": [
                    "Spectrum"
D/OkHttp:             ],
                "place_key": [
                    "netherlands"
                ],
                "subject_facet": [
                    "History",
                    "Television broadcasting",
D/OkHttp:                 "Television programs"
                ],
                "_version_": 1715091264038240257,
                "place_facet": [
                    "Netherlands"
                ],
                "lcc_sort": "PN-1992.30000000.N4 V43 1991",
                "author_facet": [
                    "OL662730A Bert van der Veer"
                ],
                "subject_key": [
                    "history",
                    "television_broadcasting",
                    "television_programs"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "num_found": 1,
D/OkHttp:     "q": "Is er iets",
        "offset": null
    }
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (2865-byte body)
```

**Base_BookTitle.kt**

```
package be.nienke.eindopdracht.api

data class Base_BookTitle (
    val numFound : Int?,
    val start : Int?,
    val numFoundExact : Boolean?,
    val docs : List<Q?>,
    val num_found : Int?,
    val q : String?,
    val offset : String?
)
```

**Q**

```
package be.nienke.eindopdracht.api

import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class Q (
    val key : String?,
    val type : String?,
    val seed : List<String?>,
    val title : String?,
    val title_suggest : String?,
    val has_fulltext : Boolean?,
    val edition_count : Int?,
    val edition_edition_key : List<String?>,
    val publish_date : List<String?>,
    val publish_year : List<Int?>,
    val first_publish_year : Int?,
    val number_of_pages_median : Int?,
    val lccn : List<Int?>,
    val publish_place : List<String?>,
    val oclc : List<Int?>,
    val contributor : List<String?>,
    val lcc : List<String?>,
    val ddc : List<Double?>?,
    val isbn : List<Int?>,
    val last_modified_i : Int?,
    val ebook_count_i : Int?,
    val ia : List<String?>,
    val public_scan_b : Boolean?,
    val ia_collection_s : String?,
    val lending_edition_s : String?,
    val lending_identifier_s : String?,
    val printdisabled_s : String?,
    val cover_edition_cover_edition_key : String?,
    val cover_i : Int?,
    val publisher : List<String?>,
    val language : List<String?>,
    val author_author_key : List<String?>,
    val author_name : List<String?>,
    val author_alternative_name : List<String?>,
    val person : List<String?>,
    val place : List<String?>,
    val subject : List<String?>,
    val time : List<String?>,
    val id_alibris_id : List<Int?>,
    val id_amazon : List<String?>,
    val id_canadian_national_library_archive : List<Int?>,
    val id_depósito_legal : List<String?>,
    val id_goodreads : List<Int?>,
    val id_google : List<String?>,
    val id_librarything : List<Int?>,
    val id_overdrive : List<String?>,
    val id_paperback_swap : List<Int?>,
    val id_wikidata : List<String?>,
    val ia_loaded_id : List<String?>,
    val ia_box_id : List<String?>,
    val publisher_facet : List<String?>,
    val person_person_key : List<String?>,
    val place_place_key : List<String?>,
    val time_facet : List<String?>,
    val person_facet : List<String?>,
    val subject_facet : List<String?>,
    val _version_ : Int?,
    val place_facet : List<String?>,
    val lcc_sort : String?,
    val author_facet : List<String?>,
    val subject_subject_key : List<String?>,
    val ddc_sort : Double?,
    val time_time_key : List<String?>
): Parcelable
```

I got the Base_BookTitle.kt and Q.kt from an online json to kotlin converter.

Comment: `After some more debugging, I found out that "adapter.submitlist(it!!.docs)" in BookListFragment.kt never happens. Why would that be?` going off of this statement alone, it won't be called if you never assign a value to `_baseBookTitle`, so are you actually assigning a value to that observable ?

Comment: what returns BookAPI.retrofitService.getBooksByTitle(_search.value!!) ?? you can see the okhttp logs to check it or debug it.  Another thing, your mutableLiveData must be private and use your livedata baseBooktitle and dont update null values, check this state in the viewmodel

Comment: @a_local_nobody i assign a value to _baseBookTitle in the init of BookListViewModel.kt

Comment: @ManuelMato I added the logcat for when I test the API. There you can see the data.

Comment: could you share your data class Base_BookTitle ? and please, check the value of the response using the debug to see if all attributes are well

Comment: If all is ok, i amnot sure because currently im not working with livedata, but retrofit by default uses the Dispatcher.IO so maybe you need to update the mutableLiveData using postValue

Comment: @ManuelMato I now added the Base_BookTitle class as well as Q.kt.

Comment: Could you maybe explain a bit more about what you mean with updating the mutableLiveData using postValue? I am a just a student so I haven't heard of this yet.

Comment: The book data looks ok... setValue is using to update the live data value in the main tread and with post value is possible to update the live data value in the background thread too.  So try to update the live data value using the post value, I am not sure if can solve your problem, if not, debug and check the response in the viewmodel, in the logs are ok to verify if the json parser is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what the problem was. I set a breakpoint at `print(e.localizedMessage)` to find the problem.

Apparently Q.kt class that I generated, was wrong.

**Q.kt**

```
package be.nienke.eindopdracht.api

import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class Q (
    val key : String?,
    val type : String?,
    val seed : List<String?>,
    val title : String?,
    val title_suggest : String?,
    val has_fulltext : Boolean?,
    val edition_count : Int?,
    val edition_edition_key : List<String?>,
    val publish_date : List<String?>,
    val publish_year : List<Int?>,
    val first_publish_year : Int?,
    val number_of_pages_median : Int?,
    val lccn : List<Int?>,
    val publish_place : List<String?>,
    val oclc : List<Int?>,
    val contributor : List<String?>,
    val lcc : List<String?>,
    val ddc : List<Double?>?,
    val isbn : List<Int?>,
    val last_modified_i : Int?,
    val ebook_count_i : Int?,
    val ia : List<String?>,
    val public_scan_b : Boolean?,
    val ia_collection_s : String?,
    val lending_edition_s : String?,
    val lending_identifier_s : String?,
    val printdisabled_s : String?,
    val cover_edition_cover_edition_key : String?,
    val cover_i : Int?,
    val publisher : List<String?>,
    val language : List<String?>,
    val author_author_key : List<String?>,
    val author_name : List<String?>,
    val author_alternative_name : List<String?>,
    val person : List<String?>,
    val place : List<String?>,
    val subject : List<String?>,
    val time : List<String?>,
    val id_alibris_id : List<Int?>,
    val id_amazon : List<String?>,
    val id_canadian_national_library_archive : List<Int?>,
    val id_depósito_legal : List<String?>,
    val id_goodreads : List<Int?>,
    val id_google : List<String?>,
    val id_librarything : List<Int?>,
    val id_overdrive : List<String?>,
    val id_paperback_swap : List<Int?>,
    val id_wikidata : List<String?>,
    val ia_loaded_id : List<String?>,
    val ia_box_id : List<String?>,
    val publisher_facet : List<String?>,
    val person_person_key : List<String?>,
    val place_place_key : List<String?>,
    val time_facet : List<String?>,
    val person_facet : List<String?>,
    val subject_facet : List<String?>,
    val _version_ : Int?,
    val place_facet : List<String?>,
    val lcc_sort : String?,
    val author_facet : List<String?>,
    val subject_subject_key : List<String?>,
    val ddc_sort : Double?,
    val time_time_key : List<String?>
): Parcelable
```

See the thing was, when the generator thought that a `List<Int>` was being returned, it was actually a list of Strings.

So, I changed every `List<Int>` to `List<String>`

**Solution:**

```
package be.nienke.eindopdracht.api

import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class Q (
    val key : String?,
    val type : String?,
    val seed : List<String?>?,
    val title : String?,
    val title_suggest : String?,
    val has_fulltext : Boolean?,
    val edition_count : Int?,
    val edition_edition_key : List<String?>??,
    val publish_date : List<String?>?,
    val publish_year : List<Int?>?,
    val first_publish_year : Int?,
    val number_of_pages_median : Int?,
    val lccn : List<String?>?,
    val publish_place : List<String?>?,
    val oclc : List<String?>?,
    val contributor : List<String?>?,
    val lcc : List<String?>?,
    val ddc : List<String?>?,
    val isbn : List<String?>?,
    val last_modified_i : Int?,
    val ebook_count_i : Int?,
    val ia : List<String?>?,
    val public_scan_b : Boolean?,
    val ia_collection_s : String?,
    val lending_edition_s : String?,
    val lending_identifier_s : String?,
    val printdisabled_s : String?,
    val cover_edition_cover_edition_key : String?,
    val cover_i : Int?,
    val publisher : List<String?>?,
    val language : List<String?>?,
    val author_author_key : List<String?>?,
    val author_name : List<String?>?,
    val author_alternative_name : List<String?>?,
    val person : List<String?>?,
    val place : List<String?>?,
    val subject : List<String?>?,
    val time : List<String?>?,
    val id_alibris_id : List<String?>?,
    val id_amazon : List<String?>?,
    val id_canadian_national_library_archive : List<String?>?,
    val id_depósito_legal : List<String?>?,
    val id_goodreads : List<String?>?,
    val id_google : List<String?>?,
    val id_librarything : List<String?>?,
    val id_overdrive : List<String?>?,
    val id_paperback_swap : List<String?>?,
    val id_wikidata : List<String?>?,
    val ia_loaded_id : List<String?>?,
    val ia_box_id : List<String?>?,
    val publisher_facet : List<String?>?,
    val person_person_key : List<String?>?,
    val place_place_key : List<String?>?,
    val time_facet : List<String?>?,
    val person_facet : List<String?>?,
    val subject_facet : List<String?>?,
    val _version_ : Long?,
    val place_facet : List<String?>?,
    val lcc_sort : String?,
    val author_facet : List<String?>?,
    val subject_subject_key : List<String?>?,
    val ddc_sort : String?,
    val time_time_key : List<String?>?
): Parcelable
```

And now my data gets displayed like it should.